# Is it safe to leave the kitchen faucet pressurized, but the flow turned off?

Tags: kitchens

My husband and I have an on going dispute about our kitchen faucet. After he gets the water to the temp he likes to wash his hands, he leaves the tap open and pressurized, but turns the flow off with a little switch at the end of the faucet. I am worried this constant pressure is bad for the plumbing lines. Especially since we had to have the kitchen faucet replaced recently because it began leaking. We have a shower head that we can leave pressurized, but then turn flow off while we soap up. This saves water, but we always turn the pressure off in the shower. I think we need to turn the pressure off at the kitchen sink too. So,is it wise to leave the kitchen faucet pressurized at all times but the flow turned off? Thank you!

Comment: Plumbing lines are always under pressure, only the faucet pass the taps usually has no pressure.  It will depend on the quality of the little switch/button, if using it long time will cause issues to it, not the pipes.

Comment: Could you be more specific on "plumbing lines"? Do you mean the supply lines under the sink and behind the walls that feed the faucet? Or do you mean some single line carrying mixed cold and hot water from the faucet's valves to its shower-head analogue?

Comment: What little switch at the end? Everyone else on the planet turns the faucet on and off alone and that's it, it's the faucets entire purpose for existing.

Comment: @whatsisname   I can see this as useful for people who wash dishes by hand when rinsing dishes.  Just hit the switch/lever to get water instead of turning off the taps(think most people just leave the water running).

Comment: Not to cause too much zizanie, but there are faucets where (by design) you set the temperature and then simply touch or wave at them to start/stop flow.

Answer (score 4):

It's harmless, with one caveat: If both hot and cold main valves are open, you've created a connection where hot water can flow into the cold-water pipes and vice versa. Depending on exactly how water is being used elsewhere in your house, and exactly how the plumbing is being routed, this *can* mean that you get temperatures other than expected elsewhere.

When you notice that, complain. Until then, I suggest you turn it off your way when you're using the sink and let him do it his way even if it is technically "wrong". It's simply not worth arguing about.